# interface generic return type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have serveral classes with similar method signatures that I wish to capture in an interface:

```
namespace MyLib

public class ClientList
    public ICollection<Client> Fetch() {
    {
        //do stuff
       return this.CreateCollection();
    }

    private ICollection<Client> CreateCollection()
    {
        List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();
        // populate list
        return clientList;
    }

public class ProductList
    public ICollection<Product> Fetch() {
        //do stuff
       return this.CreateCollection();
    }

    private ICollection<Product> CreateCollection()
    {
        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
        // populate list
        return productList ;
    }
```

I would like an interface with a method signature for Fetch that returns an ICollection, type undefined (as it will be different for every list). This will ensure each *list object will have a fetch method and new ones won't have 'getList' or other such named calls. After doing a bit of research I believe generics may be the way to go, but I'm unsure how.

I tried

```
public interface IDataRequest
    ICollection<T> Fetch<T>();
```

but when I implemented this as

```
public ICollection<Client> Fetch<Client>()
```

I got an error on 'return this.CreateCollection();':

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyLib.Client>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Client>'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I thought maybe it was because I wasn't specifying the namespace. but if I changed to

```
public ICollection<MyLib.Client> Fetch<MyLib.Client>()
```

then I got the error:

> Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type

on Fetch<MyLib.Client>()

and finally if I changed it to:

```
public ICollection<MyLib.Client> Fetch<Client>()
```

then I got the error:

> 'MyLib.ClientList' does not implement interface member 'MyLib.IDataRequest.Fetch()'. 'MyLib.ClientList.Fetch()' cannot implement 'MyLib.IDataRequest.Fetch()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'.

I don't have a big knowledge of generics and have reached the limit of what I can try with cargo cult attempts. Is what I want to do possible? If so can you show me both the interface method signature and an example of the class method definition.

As requested in a comment here is the client class:

```
namespace MyLib
{
    using System.Data;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class Client
    {
        public Client(DataRow clientRecord)
        {
            this.clientId = clientRecord.Field<string>("ID");
            this.cphh = clientRecord.Field<string>("ID");
            this.name = clientRecord.Field<string>("Name");
            this.address = clientRecord.Field<string>("Address");

            if (CommonUtilities.GIS.ValidateOSMapRef(clientRecord.Field<string>("Locationd")))
            {
                this.location = string.Format(
                    "{0}, {1}",
                    CommonUtilities.GIS.ConvertMapRefToEasting(clientRecord.Field<string>("Locationd")),
                    CommonUtilities.GIS.ConvertMapRefToNorthing(clientRecord.Field<string>("Locationd")));
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string clientId { get; private set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; private set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string address { get; private set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string location { get; private set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string cphh { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your `using`s are correct.

Comment: The return statement inside the method returns a collection of a different type than the one you've declared your method to return. How is `MyLib.Client` declared? Can you post some skeleton code of its declaration? (Including skeleton surrounding classes and/or namespaces)

Comment: @DanielA.White all these classes are in the same namespace, is there anything else I should look out for.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The Fetch method returns an ICollection of Client, the CreateCollection method returns an ICollection (List) of Client. Which is why the first attempts error message confuses me. I'll add client to the original question

Comment: there a special statement to restrict template to a type:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx , maybe it could help in your case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined your interface incorrectly. Try it like this:

```
public interface IDataRequest<T>
{
    ICollection<T> Fetch();
}
```

Then your classes look like this:

```
public class ClientList : IDataRequest<Client>
{
    public ICollection<Client> Fetch()
    {
        //do stuff
       return this.CreateCollection();
    }

    private ICollection<Client> CreateCollection()
    {
        List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();
        // populate list
        return clientList;
    }
}

public class ProductList : IDataRequest<Product>
{
    public ICollection<Product> Fetch()
    {
        //do stuff
       return this.CreateCollection();
    }

    private ICollection<Product> CreateCollection()
    {
        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
        // populate list
        return productList ;
    }
}
```

That compiles nicely.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed compile nicely, also works nicely!